# how to set default value in textbox in angularjs in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to submit comment reply by this form which is repeated in every commen

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in values">
<div style="display: none;" id="replybox{{x.cid}}">
<form name="userform" ng-submit="submitForm()">
<input type="text"  name="reply" ng-init="user.reply=1" ng-model="user.reply"/>
<input type="text"  name="parentid" ng-init="user.parentid={{x.cid}}" ng-model="user.parentid"/>
<textarea name="comment" rows="4" ng-model="user.comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"/>
</form>
</div>
<a ng-href="#" ng-click="divTogle(x.cid)" class="comment_reply" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</tr>
```

Here i want to get parentid by initializing it like this `ng-init="user.parentid={{x.cid}}"` but it's not working. i tried `ng-init="user.parentid=x.cid"`
but not working.
Reference link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: is that replybox{{x.cid}} populating correct value?

Comment: No, it either not give any value or give 12 default in every comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have the **same ng-model** for **every input** in your **ng-repeat**, that is the reason why you get 12 default value in every comment.

Try the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <div>
      <form name="userform" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <input type="text"  name="reply" ng-init="x.user.reply=1" ng-model="x.user.reply"/>
        <input type="text"  name="parentid" ng-init="x.user.parentid= x.id " ng-model="x.user.parentid"/>
        <textarea name="comment" rows="4" ng-model="x.user.comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"/>
      </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1ktRmDTXPP8QW6sqssd?p=info)

Comment: parentid display in textbox. but in form post nothing posted.

Comment: $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '../post_comment',
            data    : $scope.user,
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.values = response.data;
          });
          }

Comment: pass your row to to your submit function and use that value instead of $scope.user.

Comment: in your html change ng-submit with ng-submit(x.user) and in your controller change your function with the following $scope.submitForm = function(user) { $http({ method : 'POST', url : '../post_comment', data : user, headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(function(response) { $scope.values = response.data; }); }

Comment: I'm glad I could help.